# Detect first encounter of new line character with PowerShell v3 without loading the entire file

Tags: csv, powershell

In order to correctly load some ~10MB ~80k lines CSV files to MySQL, I need to provide a proper line terminator in the `LOAD DATA INFILE` query. Unfortunately, source CSV files come in two flavors: with newlines as `LF` (mysqldump on Linux) or `CRLF` (our DBA team crafts those).

I've been looking for a way to read file until I encounter line feed character and then figuring out which line ending is used by inspecting if carriage return precedes it.

There are plenty of `Get-Content` based examples that read either the whole file or I can read last two bytes of file. First one is too slow and inefficient, second one isn't reliable enough as some files don't have `CRLF` at the very end for some reason.

With above in mind, reading the file until I hit `LF` seems more reasonable, but I can't make `Get-Content` to "stream" the file and I don't know how far the first line ending is.

Would appreciate your ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Get-Content`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) can't do what you want, because it either reads the entire file as a single sring (`-Raw`) or as an array of lines while stripping CR and LF from the line ends.

A [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can do what you're asking for:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\your.file'

$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText($file)
$prev = $null
$char = $null
while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0 -and $char -ne 10) {
  $prev = $char
  $char = $reader.Read()
}
$reader.Close()
$reader.Dispose()

if ($prev -eq 13) {
  # file has CR-LF line breaks
}
```

Comment: this is working exactly as I wanted, much appreciated.